# I've been asked to add a Bonferroni correction to a multivariate Cox proportional hazards analysis (for overall survival)

Tags: cox-model

I've been asked to add a Bonferroni correction to a multivariate Cox proportional hazards analysis (for overall survival). I believe this is unnecessary as long as you verify the assumption of proportionality. I'd like someone with a better math background then myself to validate that my answer is correct.

For multivariate Cox proportional hazards analysis (Table 3), Bonferroni correction for Type 1 error is usually not applied, which is we believe correct if you validate the absence of Type 2 errors coming from a violation of the assumption of probability of the test. We did this by verifying assumption of proportionality for the multivariate model as described in the Statistics section (lines x to y).

Comment: What does violation of the assumptions have to do with multiple testing?

Even if all the assumptions of a model are met, if you do more tests, alpha (per paper) goes up if you keep alpha (per test) constant.